# Retrofit API not working on Navigation Drawer - Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, navigation-drawer

I am developing an Android application using Navigation Drawer.
But Retrofit API is not working on Navigation Drawer application.

When I create a new Android source project using 'Empty Activity', Retrofit API is working.
But when I create a new Android source project using 'Navigation Drawer Activity', and add code exactly same with previous source project, Retrofit API is not working.

What I did is as below.
(1) Create a new Android source project selecting 'Navigation Drawer Activity' on 'Select a Project Template'. (Min SDK : API 22 - Lollipop).

(2) Add below code in build.gralde (Project).

ext {

```
retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'

okhttpVersion = '3.9.0'
```

}

(3) Add 2 com.squareup.retrofit libraries in build.gradle(app).

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
~
```

(4) Add User Permission and android:usesCleartextTraffic in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

(5) Create a data class

public class Place {

```
@SerializedName("id")

@Expose

protected long id;

@SerializedName("x")

@Expose

protected float x;

@SerializedName("y")

@Expose

protected float y;

public Place(long id, float x, float y) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

(6) Create a Retrofit API interface.

public interface RestApi {

```
// Make Retrofit object
public static final RestApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(RestApi.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
        .build().create(RestApi.class);

String BASE_URL = "http://110.234.25.90:1330/";

@GET("places")
Call<List<Place>> getPlacesList();
```

}

(7) Create calling Retrofit API function in MainActivity and using the function in onCreate().

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getPlacesList();
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

private void getPlacesList() {
    Call<List<Place>> call = RestApi.api.getPlacesList();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Place>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Place>> call, Response<List<Place>> response) {
            List<Place> placesList = response.body();
            if(placesList != null) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Place>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is all what I did both source project.
And 'Empty Activity' source project can get data correctly, and 'Navigation Drawer Activity' source project jump to onFailure() function instead of onResponse() function.
The error message is as below.
"java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)"

What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all add both this permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

2. Uninstall/ delete the app in your device and install the application again.

hope this helped you

Comment: It worked. Now I can get data from server. Thank you so much.

Comment: please like by upvoting and mark this Answer as it answered :)